# Do diamagnetics attract or repel from magnetic field strength vector direction?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

1. If I place a ferromagnetic body in external magnetic field it will be attracted to field, and hence, body will move in the direction opposite to magnetic field strength vector direction, yes?
2. If the first statement is correct, if I place a diamagnetic body in  magnetic field, it will repeal, i.e. move in the direction of the external field?

Why am I asking?

I’ve watched video about [blood and strong magnetic field interaction](https://youtu.be/IVsWTkD2M6Q) (blood is diamagnetic fluid) and noticed, that independently on which side(north or south) of the magnet is applied to vessel with blood, it will always repeal, although in case of any ferromagnetic bar magnet it will repeal or attract dependently on what of the poles of external magnet is attached to it.

And now I am interested of considering that interaction in case of bar diamagnetic magnet(do they exist, idk?)

Answer (score 1):

> If I place a ferromagnetic body in external magnetic field it will be
>   attracted to field, and hence, body will move in the direction
>   opposite to magnetic field strength vector direction, yes?

It is better to say that it will be oriented according to the magnetic field, as happens with a compass needle.

> If the first statement is correct, if I place a diamagnetic body in
>   magnetic field, it will repeal, i.e. move in the direction of the
>   external field?

If you fix a magnetic dipole on a floating case, and put it on water, [it will travel to the side of the container](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koclT6YzeSU). The direction depends on any initial velocity. It doesn't depend on the dipole direction.

Answer (score 1):

A magnetic field *per se* does not attract or repel.  It is the gradient of magnetic field strength that attracts or repels.  Diamagnetic materials are repelled from regions where the field is stronger.